# Compiling error: "cannot find -lQtCore4"

Tags: c++, qt4, ubuntu-11.04

Yesterday I downloaded the [Qt4 Opensource library for linux](http://get.qt.nokia.com/qt/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.3.tar.gz). After running

```
./configure
./make
./make install
```

And inserting this into my .bashrc-file:

```
PATH=/usr/local/TrollTech/Qt-4.7.3/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

After this, I ran cmake in order to produce a Makefile for me. CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(VTKToVTFx)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)

include(${VTK_USE_FILE})
include(${QT_USE_FILE})

SET(VTK_TO_VTFX_FORMS main.ui)
QT4_WRAP_UI(VTK_TO_VTFX_FORMS_UIC ${VTK_TO_VTFX_FORMS})

SET(MOC_HEADERS VTKToVTFx.h)
qt4_wrap_cpp(MOC_OUTFILES ${MOC_HEADERS})

SET(CPP_SOURCES VTKToVTFx.cpp
                VTKPatch.cpp
                VTKFile.cpp
                VTKData.cpp
                VTKDataHolder.cpp
                )

add_executable(VTKToVTFx ${CPP_SOURCES} ${VTK_TO_VTFX_FORMS_UIC} ${MOC_OUTFILES})

# Adds folders for Visual Studio solution explorer (and for Xcode explorer)
source_group( "Generated"         FILES ${MOC_FILES_CPP} ${VTK_TO_VTFX_FORMS_UIC} ${QRC_FILES_CPP} ${MOC_OUTFILES})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

target_link_libraries(VTKToVTFx vtkHybrid)
target_link_libraries(VTKToVTFx QtCore4)
target_link_libraries(VTKToVTFx QtGUI4)
```

This CMakeLists.txt works perfectly well on Windows, but when I try to compile the output on my installation of Ubuntu, this error occurs:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtCore4
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtGUI4
```

Anyone who could point me to my problem here?

Comment: Slashes? Backslashes? Linux? Windows?

Comment: Sorry, I did use the correct slashes, but simply wrote it wrong here. I updated my post above. I'm using Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't use the [existing packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/libqt4-dev)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the unix[like] world, the slash is the path seperator, not the backslash.

`\usr\local\TrollTech\Qt-4.7.3\bin` evaluates to `usrlocalTrollTechQt-4.7.3bin`.

**edit:** Also, your CMakeLists.txt seems a bit foul. Have a look at http://qtnode.net/wiki/Qt4_with_cmake . Instead of

```
target_link_libraries(VTKToVTFx QtCore4)
```

use something like (source is the linked site):

---

> - To add support for Qt4 libraries like network or qttest, you need to add both the include files and corresponding libraries. For example, to add support for the network and qttest libraries, you can use:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
   ${QT_INCLUDE_DIR}
   ${QT_QTNETWORK_INCLUDE_DIR}
   ${QT_QTTEST_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(
   ${QT_LIBRARIES}
   ${QT_QTNETWORK_LIBRARIES}
   ${QT_QTTEST_LIBRARIES}
)
```

---

Even within the 4.x line of releases, libraries have been renamed and will be renamed. Fortunately there is no need for hardcodery :)

Comment: Sorry, I did use the correct slashes, but simply wrote it wrong here. I updated my post above.